# Getting error while running django_cron

Tags: django, mrjob, django-cron

When am trying to run the chron job in django using below command

```
python manage.py runcrons
```

its showing one error like below

```
$ python manage.py runcrons
No handlers could be found for logger "django_cron"
```

Does any one have any idea about this error? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is kind of given in the error you get. You are missing a handler for the "django_cron" logger. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048543/1197616. Also have a look at the docs for Django, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the solution for this.

Comment: @AkshathKumar could you please help me i got the same error. I couldnt find out the answer from the comment

Comment: @Thameem .. You have to add handlers in settings.py.Here is my code - LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/hduser/Desktop/debug.log', #/pyenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django_cron': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}

Answer (score 0):

Actually the *django-cron* library does not require a 'django_cron' logger. I resolved the same problem by running the migrations of django_cron:

```
python manage.py migrate #migrate database
```